# If $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are the Zeros of Polynomial $x^2+\sqrt[4]3x+\sqrt3=0$ . Then find : $\alpha^{96}(\alpha^{12}-1)+\beta^{96}(\beta^{12}-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $Q.$ If $\alpha$ & $\beta$ are the Zeros of Polynomial $x^2+\sqrt[4]3x+\sqrt3=0$ . Then find : $\alpha^{96}(\alpha^{12}-1)+\beta^{96}(\beta^{12}-1)$

**MY APPROACH :** let $\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}=\alpha$ . Then : $$\sqrt{\lambda}+\sqrt[4]{3}\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{3}=0$$ $$\lambda^2+3\lambda+9=0$$

We know that the root of this equation is $\alpha^4=p$

Similarly let $\sigma^{\frac{1}{4}}=\beta$ . Now we have : $$\sqrt{\sigma}+\sqrt[4]{3}\sigma^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{3}=0$$ $$\sigma^2+3\sigma+9=0$$

And the root of this equation is $\beta^4=q$ .

**DOUBT :** Now , I'm stuck here . The roots of this equation is imaginary , I'm not able to proceed kindly help .

Comment: Can you provide some context? E.g. if this is an exercise in a book right after some theorem, knowing that theorem we can provide more accurate help for you.

Comment: @Trebor This question was asked in JEE Mains 2021

Comment: How did you get this equation $\lambda^2+3\lambda+9=0$? Clearly $\sqrt{\lambda}+4\sqrt{3}\lambda^{\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{3}=0 \not\implies \lambda^2+3\lambda+9=0$.

Comment: Note that if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2 + 4 \sqrt 3 x + \sqrt 3$ and $\lambda = \alpha^4$ then $\lambda$ is a root of $x^2 + (192 \sqrt 3 - 2310) x + 9$. Is there a typo in the question perhaps?

Comment: I reverse engineered the original polynomial to be possibly $x^2 + \sqrt[4]{3} x + \sqrt{3}$, but please fix the question.

Comment: it looks like a $\sqrt 2$ snuck into $\sqrt 3$'s starring role.

Comment: @user121330 that would still make no difference, the polynomial for $\lambda$ remains incorrect.

Comment: @WimC It appears the typo has been fixed. In any event, I'm unclear on how $a + b + c = 0$ implies that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = 0$.

Comment: @user121330 It doesn't in general of course. However, the polynomial for $\lambda$ is now correct. Quite the coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT :* I need to compute : $$t^2+3t+9=0$$ $$(t-3)(t^2+3t+9)=0(t-3)$$   $$t^3=27$$

Now simply , use the value of $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ in , $$\lambda^{24}(\lambda^3-1)+\sigma^{24}(\sigma^3-1)$$

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Both $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ being roots of the quadratic $t^2+3t+9=0$ are also supposed to satisfy the equation $t^3=27$. Thus $\lambda^3=\sigma^3=27$. Now you can use this in the expression $\lambda^{24}(\lambda^3-1)+\sigma^{24}(\sigma^3-1)=2 \cdot 27^8(27-1)=52 \cdot 27^8$.